Drop duplicates where two columns are the same, if one specific column is different, replace the row
I have a very specific problem, I have a Pandas DataFrame that I am continuously adding "posts" to.
When I add new posts to the DataFrame I am currently just dropping duplicates based on the post ID, but I want to add a "Comments" column to my DataFrame which will be a list containing IDs for comments in another DataFrame.
The problem is this, if a post has new comments, I want it to either add the new comments to the comments column, or replace the entire row with the post that now has new commments.
Here is some code to give an idea of my issue:
posts = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ID', 'Date/Time', 'Title', 'Body', 'Comments'])

new_posts = get_new_posts() # Returns DataFrame containing new posts

pd.concat([posts, new_posts], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates('ID')

What I'd like to do is something like this (I know this wouldn't work)
posts = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ID', 'Date/Time', 'Title', 'Body', 'Comments'])

new_posts = get_new_posts() # Returns DataFrame containing new posts

pd.concat([posts, new_posts], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates(if 'ID' and 'Comments' else replace row)

I can't just do a flat drop duplicates, because as far as I know that would leave the old post while adding a new one with updated comments but the same ID

I actually think I have already solved the problem.. I can just drop duplicates for exact matches when concatenating and THEN I can drop duplicates based on ID

The problem was not very clear, or I did not understand it. However, if you are looking to drop duplicates that checked multiple columns, you can use the subset parameter of pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates as with a list of column names.
Example:
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     'brand': ['Yum Yum', 'Yum Yum', 'Indomie', 'Indomie', 'Indomie'],
...     'style': ['cup', 'cup', 'cup', 'pack', 'pack'],
...     'rating': [4, 4, 3.5, 15, 5]
... })
>>> print(df)
     brand style  rating
0  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
1  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
2  Indomie   cup     3.5
3  Indomie  pack    15.0
4  Indomie  pack     5.0
>>> print(df.drop_duplicates(subset=['brand', 'style']))
     brand style  rating
0  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
2  Indomie   cup     3.5
3  Indomie  pack    15.0

Source: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html
Note: If you want to keep some specific row, not a 'first' or 'last' you can use the pd.duplicated for filtering the indexes. Then you can use a specific function for selecting the row for your case on the filtered data.
